# Remember Scroll Position With Javascript when page is redirected with php $_GET statement

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm currently using Javascript to remember the scroll position of my page. The problem I am having is that when I use PHP to update something in my database and return back to the page with a $_GET statement, the script does not work to maintain the previous scroll position.

Example: if I am on a page named settings.php and I refresh the page while in a new scroll location, the script works. However, if I use a form to process some PHP data and return to something akin to settings.php?id=1 the script does not remember the scroll position. Is there a way to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. The code is below.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- This is the Java Script For maintaining scroll position. Useful for when someone is adding card quantities -->
            $(document).ready(function (e) {
                let UrlsObj = localStorage.getItem('rememberScroll');
                let ParseUrlsObj = JSON.parse(UrlsObj);
                let windowUrl = window.location.href;

                if (ParseUrlsObj == null) {
                    return false;
                }

                ParseUrlsObj.forEach(function (el) {
                    if (el.url === windowUrl) {
                        let getPos = el.scroll;
                        $(window).scrollTop(getPos);
                    }
                });

            });

            function RememberScrollPage(scrollPos) {

                let UrlsObj = localStorage.getItem('rememberScroll');
                let urlsArr = JSON.parse(UrlsObj);

                if (urlsArr == null) {
                    urlsArr = [];
                }

                if (urlsArr.length == 0) {
                    urlsArr = [];
                }

                let urlWindow = window.location.href;
                let urlScroll = scrollPos;
                let urlObj = {url: urlWindow, scroll: scrollPos};
                let matchedUrl = false;
                let matchedIndex = 0;

                if (urlsArr.length != 0) {
                    urlsArr.forEach(function (el, index) {

                        if (el.url === urlWindow) {
                            matchedUrl = true;
                            matchedIndex = index;
                        }

                    });

                    if (matchedUrl === true) {
                        urlsArr[matchedIndex].scroll = urlScroll;
                    } else {
                        urlsArr.push(urlObj);
                    }


                } else {
                    urlsArr.push(urlObj);
                }

                localStorage.setItem('rememberScroll', JSON.stringify(urlsArr));

            }

            $(window).scroll(function (event) {
                let topScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                console.log('Scrolling', topScroll);
                RememberScrollPage(topScroll);
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: I wonder if the DOM is preserved when refreshed keeping the `(el.url === windowUrl)` comparison valid, but when generating a new document; the element wont be the literal same one from the previous instance

Comment: Correct. It's kind of like why cache-busting parameters work on images and other assets. By adding a unique parameter to the url, the browser treats it as a brand new request. Unfortunately, you'll have to look into AJAX to offload a separate request to your database, or using the History API to manage application state.